# Ascertaining a doors host in the Revit API

Tags: host, revit

referencing this link...
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/door-host-wall/td-p/6951682

And considering the following C# snippet, `d` has no ``d.Host` property.

```
ICollection<Element> doors = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors).ToElements();
        foreach (Element d in doors)
        {

        }
```

However, in Python...

```
    doors = FilteredElementCollector(self.Document).OfCategory( BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors ).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

    ...

    t = Transaction(self.Document, 'This is my new transaction')
    t.Start()

    for d in doors:
        ...
        wallTypeId = d.Host.GetTypeId() 
        wall = doc.GetElement(wallTypeId)
```

I hove no problem getting the Host of d.

Looking through the Revit API, I see no reference to a Host Method or Property of an Element, However, using RevitLookUp and snooping a door, the Host is clearly ascertainable.

Why cant I collect the Host in C#?  And Why does it work in Python, even though Element doesn't seem to have a property named Host?

Answer (score 0):

Every door element is a `FamilyInstance` object, and that has a `Host` property.